# `Tslint --fix` does not autofix but instead generates lint problems as console errors

Tags: tslint, npm-scripts, codelyzer

I'm using [the Angular starter kit](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter)

and I'm trying to get tslint to autofix all my lint problems with the --fix flag.

I'm running the script:
`npm run tslint --fix src/**/*.ts`

It just generates the same error that I'm already being told about in `tslint` and not autofixing it:

console output:

```
ERROR: src/app/app-routing.module.ts[10, 5]: comment must start with a space
ERROR: src/app/app-routing.module.ts[2, 20]: Too many spaces before 'from'
```

Am I missing something that allows it to implement the changes?

My versions are:

```
"tslint": "^5.6.0"  
"codelyzer": "^3.1.2"
```

Question: How can I get tslint to implement autofix to my lint errors?

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, not all linting violations are auto-fixable.  You can see [which rules are auto-fixable here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/) by looking for the `Has Fixer` tag.

My guess is that "comment must start with a space" is governed by the [`comment-format` rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/comment-format/), which is not auto-fixable.

I'm not sure which rule is causing your second error, but it is most likely also not auto-fixable.

Here's a snippet you can run `tslint --fix` against to verify that some violations are fixed, and others are not.

```
//no var keyword (comment does not start with space)
var x: string = 'x';
console.log(x);

// array-type
let y: String[] = [];
console.log(y);

// ban-single-arg-parens
['1', '2'].filter((arg) => {
    console.log(arg);
});

// semicolon
let z: string = ''
console.log(z);

// no unused variable
let a: string = '';

// trailing comma
let list = ['1', '2', ];

// missing trailing comma
let obj = [
    1,
    2
];
```

Rules to include when linting the above file:

```
"semicolon": [true, "always"],
"trailing-comma": [true, {"multiline": "always", "singleline": "never"}],
"array-type": [true, "array-generic"],
"arrow-parens": [true, "ban-single-arg-parens"],
```

It's tempting to think that all whitespace errors would be auto-fixable, and perhaps they *should* be.  Sadly, they're not.

Comment: I'd think the best way would be to make a second linting file with only the rules you'd like to auto fix. Make a custom npm command `npm run lint-fix` which runs tslint --fix only with the specialized lint file. You can use the new command to auto fix, and you can use good ol `ng lint` just like normal still.

Answer (score 0):

Update library `tslint` and `codelyzer` to latest.

and then use this command:

`tslint --fix src/**/*.ts -t verbose` without using `npm run`

after complete, it will show to you the unfixable problems so you have to fix it manually.

You can also add it to `scripts` in `package.json` like this:

`"lint-fix": "tslint --fix src/**/*.ts -t verbose"`